# Combobox inside Form did not work

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, forms

Can anyone give me some explanation or solution about these codes. i have these errors, a combobox is in a method. when i moved the combobox outside the form(method=post), it works just fine. i dont know why it didnt work if its inside the form method and i must put it inside the form. if there's Anyone can give me a solution for this problem ill be grateful. Thank you
These are the codes:

```
<form name="baru" id="baru" action='' method='post'>
```

and then the codes below are the combobox inside the form:

```
    <select id="skala" onchange="skala()">                          
        <option value="" selected="selected">---Pilih---</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
 </form>
```

These are the javascript for the function combobox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function skala(){
    alert("zzzzzzzzzz");
    // var cb = document.getElementById('skala').value;
    // if (cb == "1" || cb == "2" || cb == "3"){
    //  $("#hemat_biaya").show();
    // }
}
</script>
```

Hope that someone can help me with this :)

Comment: where is select opening tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the syntax to below it will start working inside form

i tried to change it that way, but it still doesnt work, it didnt call the function "skala" in the javascript,

```
<select id="skala" name ="elementname" onchange="skala()">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---Pilih---</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                 </select>
```

reason why it is not working now is you are not giving name attribute in select tag for this combobox.

Comment: i tried to change it that way, but it still doesnt work, it didnt call the function "skala" in the javascript,

<select id="skala" onchange="skala()">
<option value= "" selected="selected">--Pilih---</option>

im sorry but im not used to stack overflow, thats the code that you suggested

Comment: Where is name attribute for select tag?

Comment: thankies for the advice, but it didnt work again arrrgghh, the java script function didnt work